# react leaflet marker with bage causes loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet

I'm using `react-Leaflet` and I need **multiple markers with badge** but whenever I use `onMoveEnd` on my map and `setState` something, it causes **loop and erros.**

Also when I use `onDragEnd` instead of `onMoveEnd` the loop problem goes away but i can not `drag` anymore to where ever I want.

```
const onMapMoveEnd = (e) => {
    setCenter(e.target.getCenter())
}


<Map ref={mapRef} onMoveend={(e) => onMapMoveEnd(e)}>

    markers.map( (mark, index) => <MarkerWithBadge markerIcon={myIcon}  position={position}>
    {index}
    </MarkerWithBadge>
    )
```

---

```
const MarkerWithBadge = props => {
  const initMarker = ref => {
    if (ref) {
      const popup = L.popup().setContent(props.children);
      ref.leafletElement
        .addTo(ref.contextValue.map)
        .bindPopup(popup, {
          className: "badge",
          // closeOnClick: false,
          autoClose: false
        })
        .openPopup()
        // prevent badge from dissapearing onClick
        .off("click");
    }
  };
  return <Marker ref={initMarker} {...props} />;
    };

    export default MarkerWithBadge;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the `autoPan` option of `L.popup()` to `false`. It prevents the map from panning to fit the opened popup. This is what solved it for me at least.

Doc reference: https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.6.0.html#popup.